# Get selected value in dropdown list and put it inside other dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my script :

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    var xtest = x.split("|");
    x = xtest[1];
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    var text = $('#demo').html();
    $('#texted').val(text);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    myFunction();
    $("#mySelect").change(function() {
        myFunction();
        sum();
    });
    sum();
    $("#num1, #texted").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        sum();
    });
    $("#num1").mouseup(function() {
        sum();
    });
});

function sum() {
    var num1;
    num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
    document.getElementById('sum').value = num1;
    var texted = document.getElementById('texted').value;
}
```

this is from where i'm getting the value type (text)

```
echo"<select name='id_type' id='mySelect' onchange='myFunction()' class='form-control select' data-live-search='true'>";
foreach($data as $r){
echo"<option value=".$r['id_type']."|".$r['libelle'].">".$r['libelle']."</option>";
}
echo"</select>";

<p id="demo"></p>
```

this is where i want to put the value that i have selected

```
echo"<select name='echange' id='texted' class='form-control select' data-live-search='true'>";
foreach($data as $r){
echo"<option value=".$r['id_annee'].">".$r['libelle']."</option>";
}
echo"</select>";
```

P.S the purpose of this method is to make it easy to find specific data in the last select

[image: additional screenshot]

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: i want the value of the first select inside the second select

Comment: I know i'm using php to get data from the server and put it in dropdown list

Comment: post your id `sum and num1` element too >

Comment: Once the PHP runs on that page it's done. PHP doesn't know when a value changes based on client interaction unless you AJAX the information to an external PHP page. Either way you would need to extrapolate the data with JavaScript. I'm not seeing a need for AJAX for this particular answer, but you'll want to learn it. Just use local JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine to build each list using PHP, but you'll definitely want to use JavaScript to manipulate the values of each list. For example (I'm going to use straight JS here) you could do something like this

```
list1 = document.getElementById("mySelect");
list2 = document.getElementById("texted");

list1.onblur = function() {
    list2.value = list1.options[list1.selectedIndex].value;
    //add option
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = list1.options[list1.selectedIndex].value;
    opt.innerHTML = list1.options[list1.selectedIndex].value;
    list2.appendChild(opt);
}
```